# Service broker queue message arrived but notification doesn't work

Tags: sql, notifications, service-broker

I am using the External Activator provided by Microsoft to monitor service broker queue messages. The main queue's name is "ReportQueueTarget". I also set up a notification queue like this:

```
CREATE QUEUE ReportExternalNotifyQueue
GO
-- create event notification service
CREATE SERVICE ReportExternalNotifyService
      ON QUEUE ReportExternalNotifyQueue
      (
            [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]
      )
GO

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION [ReportNotification]
ON QUEUE [ReportQueueTarget]
FOR QUEUE_ACTIVATION
TO SERVICE 'ReportExternalNotifyService','current database'
GO
```

This works fine for the two environment I set up. However, for this new environment I am setting up now, message successfully arrive in the main queue, but nothing ever shows up in the notification queue. Therefore, the external activator never receives and notification. What could cause this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question, and I know it's old. If anyone is having the same problem I have a blog post about how to troubleshoot external activation issues.

[SQL Server Service Broker troubleshooting external activation](http://blog.maskalik.com/sql-server-service-broker/troubleshooting-external-activation)